# JQuery .click(function(){}) works locally but not on the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am really confused. This piece of code works as fine as it should be on the local server on my computer. But after I uploaded it to my hostgator server, this function is not being executed anymore, since when I set the break point on firefox debugger, this function is not get called when I clicked on the class called `deck-title`. Yet locally, the break point do work and the function is called.

```
// when click the decks, the current deck should change
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".deck-title").click(function() {
        var deckTitle = $(this).text();
        $("#current-deck-span").html(deckTitle);
        if (deckTitle !== current_deck_global) {
            var deckID = getDeckIDFromTitle(deckTitle);
            updateDisplayingDeck(current_userID, deckID);
        }
        current_deck_global = $(this).text();
    });
});
```

**Any ideas on this `click(function()`?** I mean, every other JQuery code worked fine on the hostgator server, except this one...

Here is the `<head>` in my web page:

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
    <link href="./css/home.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

I am loading the JQuery script first before other script. So `$(document).ready(function())` should work (I also checked by giving every css element a border after document is ready, and yea, the borders are shown.

I really appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: can you give link to your site?

Comment: are you generating `deck-title` dynamically

Comment: why do you load twice the jquery library?

Comment: In both the server you have referred the same jQuery library? I have also confusion why you have added two jQuery library for only click event?

Comment: Yea I am generating it dynamically

Comment: i think use $(".deck-title").on('click',function() {}

Comment: also check your firebug and error console, maybe you see something that is not loaded correctly

Comment: I added two because I thought including both Jquery 1 and 2 can support IE..so I shouldn't do that?

Comment: Lol. It's not the case that you refer two jQuery libraries in same page and IE will work fine. You need to add only one jQuery library  on the page which does support the .click function which you specified above.

Comment: @rohanAM: the link is http://zkytony.com/codings/flashcard/ and you can just sign up... (it's crappy at this time)

Comment: As per your link, there is no jQuery library is being loaded on the page. you need to put and try.

Comment: you have no doctype defined!

Comment: @Pro.. Au..I see. Since I am also using the same Jquery locally, and .click() is actually added since 1.0...

Comment: I loaded them in the home page but not on the index page since I am not needing them on the index page right now...But yea, doc type. Actually what does that matter?

Comment: For DocType refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695044/what-does-doctype-html-do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your handler is running too early. Try using event delegation:

```
$(document).on("click", ".deck-title", function() {
    //.....
});
```

Comment: Yes! This is the solution!

Answer (score 1):

First of all specifiy DocType as per VDesign commented and then put this Code in your script block to verify wheather jQuery library is loaded or not.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 if (typeof(jQuery) == 'undefined') {
   var jq = document.createElement("script");
   jq.type = "text/javascript";
   jq.src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js";
   document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
 }
</script>
```

Once you load this you can add your script to as it is.

```
// when click the decks, the current deck should change
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".deck-title").click(function() {
        var deckTitle = $(this).text();
        $("#current-deck-span").html(deckTitle);
        if (deckTitle !== current_deck_global) {
            var deckID = getDeckIDFromTitle(deckTitle);
            updateDisplayingDeck(current_userID, deckID);
        }
        current_deck_global = $(this).text();
    });
});
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if your css isn't getting loaded properly because In your first link tag you have a ./ before your href string.  I would try removing that