# Safari on Iphone 4/5 display percentage incorrectly

Tags: html, css, iphone, responsive-design

So I'm working on responsive design and I thought I was almost there when I noticed the issue on the apple phones. [This](http://social-project.eu5.org) is the link and you probably can see how it looks on android, all ok but on iphone is a completly different story. I noticed this by accident, I was chatting with a friend and I wanted to show him my project(he had an iphone 5), and then when the page loaded I felt a little idiotic. The thing is I have NO ways to simulate but to ask my friends, and I am not always with them and such so it is kinda difficult. It does not work with developer kit from chrome because it does not show that issue.

I surfed the net and thought it could be the issue about that safari rounds down
 decimals. So a little help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have checked your site and its working great in android as well as chrome but sorry no iphone but tomorrow from office i will sure give it a try to help you..:)

Comment: @Leothelion thanks ;)

Comment: <!doctype html5> => <!doctype html> , can solve it..  http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp  , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695044/what-does-doctype-html-do

Comment: @PhilAndelhofs doesn't work

Comment: @Sashka https://www.browserling.com/ is an option to check for yourself..   troubels with <img> they are not correct at all and that can give you an issue on safari.. i'm looking now...

Comment: O: The <img> tag has two required attributes: src and alt. source: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp

Comment: problem is flex: wrap on safari 6 or lower,  http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Comment: Well Sashka, your issue is resolved.. m free :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.header__inner > *, .add_friend, .more__info, .show__notifications { float:left; }
```

This is what i added.. because of flex-wrap is ignored in Safari < 7, i float element to left  (selector > * means direct child of selector).

than you have to make a finishing touch and you will available in Safari < 7.
[image]

edit: browser detection with version (unable to know for sure if works perfect, but quick test gives, safari on safari, chrome on chrome, firefox on firefox and MSIE and IE on IE

```js
function get_browser_info(){
    var ua=navigator.userAgent,tem,M=ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie|trident(?=\/))\/?\s*(\d+)/i) || []; 
    if(/trident/i.test(M[1])){
        tem=/\brv[ :]+(\d+)/g.exec(ua) || []; 
        return {name:'IE',version:(tem[1]||'')};
        }   
    if(M[1]==='Chrome'){
        tem=ua.match(/\bOPR\/(\d+)/)
        if(tem!=null)   {return {name:'Opera', version:tem[1]};}
        }   
    M=M[2]? [M[1], M[2]]: [navigator.appName, navigator.appVersion, '-?'];
    if((tem=ua.match(/version\/(\d+)/i))!=null) {M.splice(1,1,tem[1]);}
    return {
      name: M[0],
      version: M[1]
    };
 }

var browser=get_browser_info();
alert(browser.name);
```

Comment: Is there a special to identify safari version < 7 so that I can load a specific css? LiKe we did for the IE in the head section?

Comment: @Sashka sure, i edited answer, also you could make a few simple css changes that i looks fine in safari < 7.. (example: min-height on the grey box.. (maybe in media query) than i looks fine for everyone :) )