# Is it mandatory/necessary to specify the character set (character encoding) used in HTML5 document?

Tags: html, utf-8, character-encoding, meta

As per my knowledge : **For HTML5, the default character encoding is UTF-8.**

and the type of HTML document is recognized as HTML5 document by the `<!DOCTYPE html>` declaration at the very beginning of HTML page.

Then, my question is as the browser come to know from the `<!DOCTYPE html>` declaration that the document type of the current HTML document is **HTML5** and **the default character encoding for HTML5 document is UTF-8.**

Then, is it mandatory/necessary to specify the character set (character encoding) used in HTML5 document unless I use some different character encoding like **(ISO-8859-1, ANSI(Windows-1252), ASCII, etc.)**?

Can I use some other character encoding like **(ISO-8859-1, ANSI(Windows-1252), ASCII, etc.)** in my **HTML5** document? If yes, do all modern browsers support it? If no, why? What's the reason behind it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does <!doctype html> do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695044/what-does-doctype-html-do)

Comment: @NIKHILNEDIYODATH : My question is different. I'm not asking about <!DOCTYPE html> declaration. So, please unmark my question as duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the charset meta tag required with HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14669352/is-the-charset-meta-tag-required-with-html5)